# pandas numpy KeyError: "['1' '2' '3' '4'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe,you can have it by running this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df4s = """
   LowerAge    age    1       2      3      4 
0  2            3     o.234   o.234  o.234  o.234
1  3            4     o.234   o.234  o.234  o.234
2  4            2     o.234   o.234  o.234  o.234      
3  5            3     o.234   o.234  o.234  o.234         
"""
df4 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df4s.strip()), sep='\s+')

df4
```

The ouput is:

```
  LowerAge  age   1       2       3       4
0   2       3     o.234   o.234   o.234   o.234
1   3       4     o.234   o.234   o.234   o.234
2   4       2     o.234   o.234   o.234   o.234
3   5       3     o.234   o.234   o.234   o.234
```

Now the logic is like this: for each row ,if LowerAge-1 < age,then df4[str(LowerAge-1)] =1,or it will stay the same,for example:

In the first row,LowerAge-1 equals 1 and  it is less than age，then value of column '1'(because LowerAge-1 equals 1) will equal 1,

in the second row, LowerAge-1 equals 2 and  it is less than age， then value of column '2' will equal 1.

The final output should be:

```
  LowerAge  age  '1'     '2'     '3'     '4'
0   2       3     1      o.234   o.234   o.234
1   3       4     o.234  1       o.234   o.234
2   4       2     o.234  o.234   o.234   o.234
3   5       3     o.234  o.234   o.234   o.234
```

My code is:

```
lower_v=df4['LowerAge'].values - 1

df4[lower_v.astype(str)]=np.where(lower_v<df4['age'],1,df4[lower_v.astype(str)])
```

Error:

```
---> 19 df4[lower_v.astype(str)]=np.where(lower_v<df4['age'],1,df4[lower_v.astype(str)])
KeyError: "['1' '2' '3' '4'] not in index"
```

Any friend can hlep?

Comment: If you want to working in pandas dataframe by row, use `.iloc`

Comment: Thank you for your reply,can you post your reply as an answer ,so that I can check it?

Comment: At least with this example, the column labels are such a mess, because they aren't just the string `'1'`, the are the string with the quotes, `''1''`, so If you needed to actually reference them by label you'd need something like `df["'1'"]`

Answer (score 0):

Won't fix your code, but the current error is due to the fact your columns are `'1'` or `'2'` with quotes. Removing these quotes in the df definition got rid of this error, but your code didn't return the expected result either:

```
df4s = """
   LowerAge    age    1      2     3       4  
0  2            3     o.234   o.234  o.234  o.234
1  3            4     o.234   o.234  o.234  o.234
2  4            2     o.234   o.234  o.234  o.234      
3  5            3     o.234   o.234  o.234  o.234         
"""
```

Comment: Thank you ,I updated my question.

Comment: better you mention it in comments

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do slicing to solve this problem, so you can try this :

```
for i in range(len(df4)):
    index_age = df4['LowerAge'].iloc[i]-1
    if index_age<df4['age'].iloc[i]:
        df4.iloc[i,index_age+1] = 1
```

And the result :
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply,it looks very good,my only concert is ,if the file size is very large,this method may run very slowly,is there any numpy way can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
def fun(x):
  if x['LowerAge']-1<x['age']:
    if x['LowerAge']-1<4:
      x[str(x['LowerAge']-1)]=1
  return x
df4.apply(fun,axis=1)
```

output:

```
  LowerAge  age  '1'     '2'     '3'     '4'
0   2       3     1      o.234   o.234   o.234
1   3       4     o.234  1       o.234   o.234
2   4       2     o.234  o.234   o.234   o.234
3   5       3     o.234  o.234   o.234   o.234
```

coming to time complexity linear complexity is must thing as we need to check for every row. There might be better solutions but this solution wont cost you much.

Comment: Any way to remove 4 in the second condition and make it apply to any number of columns, i.e, `if str(x['LowerAge'] - 1) in df4.columns`?

Comment: Yes we can directly write the statement x[str(x['LowerAge']-1)]=1 in that  outside if without using that if statement at all. What we were doing is we checked if a column with that name exist or not to avoid key error in case you are sure that every number exist as a column then you can just skip that if statement and write it's content outside it.

Comment: if x['LowerAge']-1<x['age']:
      x[str(x['LowerAge']-1)]=1